# Add Azure Credentials - The provided credentials are not valid

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to add the Azure credentials (Microsoft Azure Service Principal) on jenkins server under

Manage Jenkins -> configure System -> Add cloud -> Microsoft Azure VM Agent -> Add Azure Credentials

I have created SPN, provided contributor access at the subscription level, copied subscription ID, Application id, application secrete to create credential but When I click Verify Service Principal I am getting error invalid credentials.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you follow this one: https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/jenkins-azure/new/create-cred?

Comment: Yes these are the same steps.